# Removing everything included all spaces in a list that doesn't equal a desired string

Tags: python, list

I have this list containing a bunch of strings:

```
list = ['hi','         how        ','are','you']
```

How can I remove every element in the list (and the corresponding text within those strings ) that doesn't equal a specific string such as "hi"

such that the final list is

```
list = ['hi']
```

as a first step I tried stripping the spaces:

its odd because I tried stripping the elements of spaces using:

```
newList = []


for i in list:
    str(i).replace(' ','')
    newList.append(i)
```

but I keep getting the same results with the big spaces in between, is there any way to remove spaces and any strings that dont match my specified string in one efficient algorithm?

Comment: Have you tried filtering the list in anyway?

Comment: Only `.strip()` is sufficient to remove leading/trading whitespaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `space` to `''`
Compare each element and `'hi'`.

```
list = ['hi','         how        ','are','you']
list = [x.strip(' ') for x in list]
print (list)
list = [x for x in list if 'hi' == x]
print (list)
```

Result:

```
['hi', 'how', 'are', 'you']
['hi']
```

Comment: now what if I wanted to strip the spaces first, would I need a separate list comprehension to take care of that?

Comment: How come your stripping of the white space works and this doesnt: 

list = [elem for elem in list if elem.strip("  ")]

Comment: @CosmicCat  Sure. It's better. Updated again. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an empty list (in this case, 'hi_list')
2. Go through all the values in list, looking for 'hi'
3. If you find 'hi', append it to 'hi_list'

   ```
   hi_list = list()

   for x in range(0, len(list)):
   if (list[x] == 'hi'):
       hi_list.append(list[x])
   ```

Answer (score 0):

use `strip()` instead of `replace()` it is more easier

```
mylist = ['hi','         how        ','are','you']

stripped_list = [x.strip() for x in mylist]  # remove spaces
final_list = [x for x in stripped_list if x == 'hi']  # filter list

print(stripped_list)
print(final_list)
```

output:

```
['hi', 'how', 'are', 'you']
['hi']
```